# No output warning when no checkboxes are selected.

Tags: java, checkbox

This code gets how many checkboxes (nchecked) are selected.  It works when more than 2 boxes are selected, but no warning is outputted when I have no checkboxes selected.
What should be different?

Here's the code that gets the checkboxes

```
private int getCheckBoxes(){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.size(); i++){
        if (checkBoxes.get(i).isSelected()) {
        count++;
    }
    }
    return count;
}

private int getIndex(String cityName) {
    return cities.indexOf(cityName);        
}

//Here is the code that I'm putting out my warning

private void handleCitySelection (int index) {
    if (checkBoxes.get(index).isSelected()) 
    { 
        int nchecked = getCheckBoxes();
        if (nchecked <= 0)
        {
            outputDistance.append("Please Select 2 Cities");
        }            
        if(nchecked >= 3)
        {
            checkBoxes.get(index).setSelected(false);
        }
        else 
            if (nchecked == 1) {
                city1 = index;
            }
        else 
            {
                city2 = index;
            }
    }
}
```

Also behind each checkbox is:

```
handleCitySelection(getIndex(evt.getActionCommand()));
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well since your warning is only shown on when a check box is selected, you need some way to tie your warning code to what ever it is that is happening when you want to check that no boxes are selected. Try a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps when you call this line

```
if (checkBoxes.get(index).isSelected())
```

you are only performing the following if/else statements if the box at the index is checked. If none are checked you will not execute those statements and thus not print the warning

Comment: Sorry, so I would write instead?

Comment: you could first check if they have selected 1 or 2 cities. If not, send warnings... and then once you know they have selected 1 or 2. set it to the proper city